# XCode, iOS: Label not appearing in view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I dragged a label into my view, but when I run the application the label does not appear. why?

[image: label called labjel added to view]

[image: labjel does not appear when app is run]

Comment: Can you add the constraints image? Where you set the label text?

Comment: If you have created an `@IBOutlet` or `@IBAction` please use `command + F` and search your label name to show us all code related to the label. (You can also do this for the view the label is in as that may be causing the problem)

Answer (score -1):

Yeah you must check the constraints about the label ,I recommended you to use code to do the related job, you can debug it via playground ....
Based on the image, cannot judge the issue